# Regex matching capital characters, numbers and period

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to see if a input only contains capital letters, numbers and a period in regex. What would the regex pattern be for this in Java?

Is there any guides on how I can build this regex, even some online tools?

Also is it possible to check length of string is no more than 50 using regex?

Comment: Capital letters would be [A-Z], Numbers [0-9] period [\.] (needs to be escaped) from i.e. 10-50 characters would be {10,50} in combination [\.0-9A-Z]{10,50} should match your character combination from 10 to 50 characters in length (not 51)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Unicode answer:

```
^[\p{Lu}\p{Nd}.]{0,50}$
```

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

> \p{Lu} or \p{Uppercase_Letter}: an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.
>
> \p{Nd} or \p{Decimal_Digit_Number}: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.

`^` and `$` is the start and the end of the string

Comment: `$` is not the end of string in Java.  That's `\z`.  `$` is the same as `\Z` normally.

Comment: @MikeSamuel That’s getting a bit technical. `$` is normally `\n?\z`, but that’s close enough for most regular work.

Comment: @tchrist - Hey! I'm an ASCII brain! But maybe your [new book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596004923) will help to enlighten me - (it just shipped today - Yay!) _Real_ Perl regex, here I come!

Comment: How would this be done in java? I'm trying to use `Pattern.compile("^[\p{Lu}\p{Nd}.]{0,50}$");` but it isn't working.

Comment: How would this be done in java? I'm trying to use `Pattern.compile("^[\p{Lu}\p{Nd}.]{0,50}$");` but it isn't working.

Comment: @Jeff BBeeccaauussee  JJaavvaa  llaacckkss  11ˢˢᵗᵗ--ccllaassss  rreeggeexxeess,,  yyoouu  hhaavvee  ttoo  ddoouubbllee  tthhee  bbaacckkssllaasshheess..

Comment: @ridgerunner Between the greatly expanded regex chapter, the new Unicode chapter, and the charnames pragma alone, there’s more than 150 pages of stuff dealing with Unicode. Should fix your ASCII-brain, eh? :)

Answer (score 3):

Regex pattern:

`Pattern.compile("^[A-Z\\d.]*$")`

To check the length of a string:

`Pattern.compile("^.{0,50}$")`

Both combined:

`Pattern.compile("^[A-Z\\d.]{0,50}$")`

Although I wouldn't use regular expressions to check for length if I were you, just call `.length()` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) website is really handy for building and testing and regular expressions

Comment: @anubhava: "Is there any guides on how I can build this regex, even some online **tools**?"

Comment: @Guvante: You can use http://www.regular-expressions.info as a reference manual for regex.

Comment: @anubhava: "It's not an answer, just a comment", and he linked to an online tool, which does answer one of his questions.

Comment: @Guvante: Agreed, deleted my comment and upvoted this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions in Java have a lot in common with other languages when it comes to the simple syntax, with some predefined character classes that add more than you'd find in Perl for example. The [Java API docs on Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) show the various patterns that are supported. A friendlier introduction to regexes in Java is [http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html](http://regular-expressions.info).

Some very quick Googling shows there are many tools online for testing Java regular expressions against input strings. [Here is one](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm).

To check for the type of input you are interested in, the following regex should work:

`^[A-Z0-9.]{,50}$`

Broken down, this is saying:

`^`: start matching from the start of the input; do not allow the first character(s) to be skipped

`[]`: match one of the characters in this range

`A-Z`: within a range, `-` means to accept all values between the first and last character inclusive, so in this case all characters from A to Z.

`0-9`: add to the previous range all digits

`.`: periods are special in regexes, but all special characters become simple again within a character class (`[]`)

`{,50}`: require  (or 0) matches up to 50 of the character class just defined.

`$`: the match must reach the end of the input; do not allow the last character(s) to be skipped

Comment: `$` allows the last character to be skipped if it is a line terminator.  `\z` matches the end of input.

Answer (score 0):

This returns true for strings, containing only 50 characters that can be numbers, capital letters or a dot.

```
string.matches("[0-9A-Z\\.]{0,50}")
```

Comment: Except that without anchoring the beginning and the end of your regex, you are saying that you want strings where *some substring* matches your regex pattern.

Comment: No, that's not neccessary. This statement returns false for "nonCAPITAL", even though a substring ("CAPITAL") would match.

Comment: Shoot, sorry.  Should have paid a bit more attention to the language (Java, which I haven't messed with in a while.).  Most languages I know let you "test" against a regex, but that could match any substring, which, of course, would screw you over.  That doesn't appear to be the case with the Java.matches function.

Answer (score 0):

In response to what tools you can use, I prefer [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)